# Google Chrome Extensions: Passing user highlighted webpage text to a browser_action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working on a Chrome extension where I need to pass highlighted text into a browser_action. I found the following code in a Google Group, and at the time it was written it was still valid - but it doesn't work anymore..

Does anyone know an alternative solution?

**background.html:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var selection_callbacks = [];

      function getSelection(callback) {
        selection_callbacks.push(callback);
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "contentscript.js" });
      };

      chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function (request) {
        var callback = selection_callbacks.shift();
        callback(request);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.html:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function onSelection(text) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = text;
      }
      chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().getSelection(onSelection);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="output">
      This should be replaced with the selected text
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**contentscript.js:**

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest(window.getSelection().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a real [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) instead of injecting JavaScript into the page with chrome.extension.executeScript. You could then have background.html ask the content script for the selection using [chrome.tabs.sendRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendRequest).